# Event Handler for A Rebus Topic

Tags: rebus

As we know that Rebus provides Topic Based routing in addition to the familiar TypeBased routing although we are told that the TypeBased routing follows the same principle. 
On my side however unfortunately I have not seen a good example on how to create a handler that processes messages published to a particular topic.

Suppose I publish my message as follows

```
var message=new Student { StudentID=90008,FirstName="Chilipo",LastName="Mjengo" };

await bus.Advanced.Topics.Publish("rebus_example_topic", message);
```

In another endpoint I have subscribed to the topic as follows

```
await bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe("rebus_example_topic");
```

My interest is to know how do I then implement the Handler that will process the messages published to the rebus_example_topic.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, actually  the preferred way of writing message handlers is to implement `IHandleMessage<TMessage>`, where `TMessage` is your message type.

In your case that would be

```cs
public class StudentHandler : IHandleMessages<Student>
{
    public async Task Handle(Student message)
    {
        // handle your message in here
    }
}
```

How you then activate your message handler depends on which handler activator, you're using. The "handler activator" is what you use to instantiate message handlers, so you just need to register your handler in that to make it available to Rebus.

Some container integrations even come with additional help in the form of registration extensions, so e.g. if you're using Autofac, you can register your handler like this:

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterHandler<StudentHandler>();
```